# Visual Studio Code for Xelatex latexmkrc with Beamer and Minted for Musixtex

Tags: beamer, minted, musixtex, vscode

It is required to configure the Visual Studio Code for Xelatex latexmkrc with Beamer and Minted for Musixtex. For that I configure the following files:

1. latexmkrc:

   ```python
   $xelatex = 'internal musixlatex %R %O %S';
   push @generated_exts,"mx2";
   push @generated_exts,"mx1";

   sub musixlatex {
      my $root = shift;
      # Define root filename for the mx1 and mx2 files
      # Note that $aux_dir1 includes directory separator
      #      and it equals $out_dir1 if only the out_dir is set.
      my $mx = "$aux_dir1$root";
      my @args = @_;
      if ( $pass{$rule} <= 1 ) { 
         print "======= FIRST PASS: Deleting '$mx.mx2' =======\n";
         unlink "$mx.mx2"; 
         print "====   Generating '$mx.mx1' then '$mx.mx2' ===\n";
         my $ret = system( "xelatex @args" );
         if ($ret) { return $ret; }
         $ret = system( "musixflx $mx" );
         if ($ret) { return $ret; }
      }
      return system( "xelatex @args" );
   }
   ```
2. settings.json:

   ```python
   {
       "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",
       "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
       "latex-workshop.latex.tools": [{
           "name": "latexmk",
           "command": "latexmk",
           "args": [
               "--shell-escape",
               "-xelatex",
               "-synctex=1",
               "-interaction=nonstopmode",
               "-file-line-error",
               "%DOC%"
           ]
       }],
   "editor.accessibilitySupport": "off",
   "chronicler.ffmpeg-binary": "c:\\Users\\Aland\\Downloads/ffmpeg.exe",
   "window.zoomLevel": 1
   }
   ```
3. The Latex beamer code (note that is needed to configure the minted for Latex code, and customize it for Musixtex):

   ```latex
   \documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
   \usepackage{musixtex}

   \usepackage{minted}
   \usemintedstyle{borland}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{frame}[t]
   \frametitle{\large Musixtex code}

   \begin{minted}{latex}
       \begin{music}
           \setclef1\treble % Clave de Sol para el Instrumento 1
           \nobarnumbers % Omite la numeración en los compases
           \nostartrule % Inicia sin barra vertical
           \startextract %inicia el fragmento musical
           %Primer compás
           \NOTEs \wh{ghijkl^mn}  \en\setdoubleBAR
           \endextract % Se finaliza el fragmento musical
         \end{music}
   \end{minted}

   \end{frame}

   \end{document}
   ```

Note: I already install pygmentize, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `fragile` frame option if you have such fragile content as a source code listing:

```
% !TeX program = txs:///arara
% arara: xelatex: {synctex: on, interaction: nonstopmode, shell: yes}
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{musixtex}

\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{borland}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{\large Musixtex code}

\begin{minted}{latex}
    \begin{music}
        \setclef1\treble % Clave de Sol para el Instrumento 1
        \nobarnumbers % Omite la numeración en los compases
        \nostartrule % Inicia sin barra vertical
        \startextract %inicia el fragmento musical
        %Primer compás
        \NOTEs \wh{ghijkl^mn}  \en\setdoubleBAR
        \endextract % Se finaliza el fragmento musical
      \end{music}
\end{minted}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]